# Java: Object reference inside Object that contains original Object reference

Tags: java, object, reference, linked-list

So I struggled for quite a while to find documentation about this and failed. The question is more of "How it works" rather than explanation over a snippet of code.

The trouble:

```
xObject x = new xObject();
yObject y = new yObject( x );

x.add( y );
```

Where `xObject` has:

```
private ArrayList<yObject> yObjects;    

public void add( yObject _y ) {
    this.yObjects.add( _y );
}
```

And `yObject`has:

```
private xObject x;

public yObject( xObject _x ) {
    this.x = _x;
}
```

Now Is it possible to play around with the `y`s from the ArrayList inside x?

Trying to figure things out by testing is impossible since whenever I try, I don't seem to have the necessary brain power not to get confused (Reason why I was hoping more intelligent people than me in here may be able to help out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayList<yObject>` does not contain yObjects:  It contains *references* to yObjects.  The only thing that actually *contains* any of your objects is the heap.

It's no different from how you can put your friend's name in the "contacts" list on your phone, and she can put your name in the contacts list on her phone.  There's no paradox because neither one of your contacts lists contains actual people:  The lists only contain information about how to get hold of people.  Likewise, Java variables and Java containers don't actually contain objects:  They only contain the information needed to *find* those objects and interact with them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play with y inside x, because it's reference to object. So if you update y in x, y outside x will be also updated.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that `x` contains a list of `y`s in which one of the `y`s contains the same `x` that contained the list?

Comment: Yes, that's the situation. "_But doesn't that mean_" seems to indicate you're skeptical of something.

Comment: You'll have infinite reference ;)

Java will handle it ;)

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider and doesn't that produce an infinite loop? Or is it that if it's not a new instance of any of them, then it's just magically fine?

Comment: @hya Well that's awesome, I'll mark this as answer, maybe there are others out there struggling with this, Thank You.

Comment: @Denis Makula is there a reason why this would be an issue? There's nothing (technically, at least) wrong with two objects holding references to each other.